# iphone navigation controller - transition between portrait and landscape view controllers

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

In my iphone app, i've two view controllers. First one is a portrait and second one is landscape.
When app is started, it will show the portrait view. On click of a button in portrait view, the view transitions to landscape view. Here, i'm using navigation controller.
If both the views are portrait, pushing the next view via navigation controller won't be a problem. How can I achieve transition between portrait and landscape views using nav controller.
Note that status bar is visible and nav bar is hidden.

Comment: Excuse me, but what is the problem exactly? And what do you mean by "transition between portrait and landscape views"?

Comment: As explained, first viewcontroller is portrait and second one landscape viewcontroller. i'm using navigation controllers "pushViewController" to show landscape viewcontroller. but landscape view controller is not rotating.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the following instead of pushViewController

```
[self presentModalViewController:aController animated:YES];
```

This is the only solution i guess. If you are navigating further from the LandScape mode put the aController inside the UINavigationController and Present the NavController the same way as shown above.